# Access database wont open on other machine

Tags: ms-access

I have an access 2016 database that im creating and it works fine on my computer and a colleagues computer.

It doesnt work on the computers of the people im making it for.
They have access 2016.

They try to open the database and it just opens the create a new database menu. Nothing comes up at all.
They can open other databases but just not mine.
2 people on 2 machines tried it

I tried to load everything into a new fresh database and it didnt work.
Also I ensured only the default references were used.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: Did you check the Trusted Locations and Macro settings in the Trust Center? How did you transfer the file? If you downloaded it from the Internet did you unblock the file?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Yes, checked the trust centre and i set it to enable all.